# Find the number of pairwise non-isomorphic subspaces of $\Bbb R^m × \Bbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Find the number of pairwise non-isomorphic subspaces of vector space $\Bbb R^m × \Bbb R^n$ .

We know that for any $n\in\Bbb N$, every $n$-dimensional vector space over the field $\Bbb R$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. In particular, every subspace of $\Bbb R^m$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$ for some $n$. What are the candidates for $n$? Clearly $n\le m$, so $n$ must be $0,1,2,3,...,m$. so $\Bbb R^m$ has exactly $m+1$ pairwise non-isomorphic subspaces.

So $\Bbb R^m × \Bbb R^n$ has exactly $(m+1)(n+1)$ pairwise non-isomorphic subspaces. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

For $n\geq2$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has infinitely many subspaces (for instance, the sets underlying the $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the straight lines through the origin, that is, the sets $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ax+by=0\}$ for fixed $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, of which there are uncountably many) so we should perhaps restate the question as "What is the largest possible size of a set of pairwise non-isomorphic subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ ?"

Since $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, therefore by your earlier argument, the answer is $m+n+1$.